# How do I hide axes and ticks in matlab without hiding everything else

Tags: matlab

I draw images to axes in my matlab UI, but I don't want the axes and ticks to be visible how do I prevent that, and also where do I make this call?

I do this

```
imagesc(myImage,'parent',handles.axesInGuide);
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
axis off;
```

Is this what you are looking for?

This is definitely somewhere else on this website and in the matlab documentation. Try typing

`help plot`

Or using the documentation on plotting!

edit: Now that you have shown what you are doing. (You don't need the handles, I just always write them in to clutter my workspace)

```
myImage = yurbuds0x2Dironman; # don't ask
fH = figure;
iH = imagesc(myImage);
set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
```

Are you able to do it like this?

Comment: Note that 'box off' is also useful, especially in combination with set(gcf,'Color',[0 0 0])

Answer (score 7):

I support the

```
set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[]);
```

approach over the

```
axis off
```

one. The reason is `set(gca, ...)` just removes the labels but keeps the axes, unlike `axis off`. I am generating a group of images with fixed dimensions to combine later into a video. Deleting the axes creates different size frames that can't be recombined.

Comment: For exporting frames into a video, I have the best experience with getframe(gcf), which saves the figure content, whatever the exas currently are (also extremely useful when exporting a video of rotating 3D axes!)